# Capture SMTP traffic over long time period

Tags: windows-xp, smtp, logging, wireshark

We have an SMTP relay (just an XP box with SMTP) on our network. It's hanging around because some legacy apps used to use it so send emails from code.

It hardly gets any traffic, I can see from the SMTP log that it's only used every few days, if that.

Before I turn it off, I want to track where the emails are coming from (I can see the originating server, but I want to be able to see the SMTP header to get sender, recipient and if possible the body.)

How can I do this over a long period of time? I thought about wireshark, but am planning on leaving it running for a couple of weeks. Is this manageable or is there a better solution?

Comment: what smtp software is the xp box running?

Comment: Read the email headers... by opening the emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no idea about wireshark + windows, but using linux + tcpdump (almost equivalent from what I've heard), I had no problem capturing traffic for a few days provided that there is :

- Enough disk space
- Not much traffic
- Port (25) is specified so that captures dont grow too big.

Comment: I might be being thick here. . . I've set a capture filter (having removed all the others to 'smtp' (without quotes). However my capture still shows loads of traffic flowing. If I set the display fliter to smtp, I see just SMTP traffic. How do I ensure I only capture smtp so my capture file doesn't grow enormous?

Comment: No idea sorry. With tcpdump it's "tcpdump -i eth0 -s 0 port 25".

Comment: isn't this a windows box?

Comment: @austin yes : That's why I said I had "no idea"

Comment: haha. that was my point. on a linux box yes this would be the answer but for windows this will not work. just wondering why he marked it solved if in fact this isn't the right answer.

Comment: Are you sure this is impossible on windows? This page states it works : http://www.winpcap.org/windump/docs/manual.htm

Comment: it would appear you can use tcpdump in the windows env so marking resolved is def justified. however your post explicitly said linux. but whatever. details :)

Answer (score 1):

i know you said no wireshark but i think you should. simply add capture filters to your specific addresses that you know the email are originating from. you could also try and capture just X number of bytes to just attempt to get the header. 
check - [capture filters](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters)

Comment: You could also apply a capture filter for just SMTP traffic. That should reduce the amount of traffic captured significantly.

Comment: Trying to do that, but struggling getting the capture filter to capture just smtp. Can do a display filter, but I assume that doesn't prevent the other packets being logged.

Comment: well since very few hosts are relaying on this server, you probably know exactly which hosts are using this server. if that's the case, simply capture just those packets. that will cut your capture size down and then you can filter out `SMTP`.